# Evaluate $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{1}{x\sin(x)\tan(x\sin(x))}-\frac{1}{x^2\sin^2(x)} \right) $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Calculate the limit
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{1}{x\sin(x)\tan(x\sin(x))}-\frac{1}{x^2\sin^2(x)} \right)
$$
My try was to use the Taylor expansion of the denominator and numerator but it wasn't beauty approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=x\sin x$

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{u\tan u}-\dfrac{1}{u^2}\right)=\lim_{u\to 0}\dfrac{u-\tan u}{u^2\tan u}$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: I've corrected some errors, but the conversion back to $x$-space is unnecessary.

Comment: I'll remove that then @J.G.Thanks. Cheers :))

Comment: Thanks, whats the official arguemnt to change $x\sin(x)$ to $u$?

Comment: Simply put in $x\sin x$ for $u$ and see that as $x\to 0$ then $u=x\sin x\to 0$.

Comment: @avan1235 $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=\lim_{u\to\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}f(u)$ provided $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists.

Comment: @avan1235: the rule of substitution in limits is as follows: if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =L$ and $\lim_{x\to b} g(x) =a$ and $g(x) \neq a$ as $x\to b$ then $$\lim_{x\to b} f(g(x)) =L=\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $$ Here $g(x)=x\sin x, a=b=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The function you want to compute the limit of is even, so you can as well consider the limit for $x\to0^+$.

Consider the function $f(x)=x\sin x$, defined and positive in a some interval $(0,\delta)$, has limit $0$ for $x\to0^+$ and $f'(x)=\sin x+x\cos x$. Thus we can assume $f'(x)>0$ over $(0,\delta)$. Thus $f$ is continuous and invertible over $(0,\delta)$ and therefore the substitution $u=x\sin x$ is possible. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left( \frac{1}{x\sin(x)\tan(x\sin(x))}-\frac{1}{x^2\sin^2(x)} \right)
=\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{u-\tan u}{u^2\tan u}
$$
which is easy if you recall that
$$
\tan u=u+\frac{1}{3}u^{3}+o(u^3)
$$